# With Freebase Suggest how do I filter one field based on the selection of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, location, freebase

If I'm using Freebase Suggest ( http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Freebase_Suggest ) and I have one field that selects either Country or State, how do I then have another field "City" filter to display only cities in that Country or State?

Also, if someone selected as their State "New York" ("/en/new_york"), how would I query to find out the "Country" is "United States of America"?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't as easy as you'd hope. You can look at the /location/location/contained_by property of the city and see if /en/united_states (or whatever you're looking for) is included in there. However, this won't give you all the answers you're hoping for - for example, if you look at /en/new_york you'll see that it's contained by /en/new_york_state, but there's no direct link to /en/united_states.

You can look at /en/new_york_state and find that's contained by /en/united_states, but there's no easy way to do that kind of "transitive" search in Suggest.

The only thing you can do is to use the "[included](http://emql.freebaseapps.com/edit?id=/location/location/inside)" MQL extension, but that relies on correct geodata being present in Freebase.

With regards to New York (State) being part of the United States, just look at the /location/administrative_division/country.

Hope this helps!